# Having issue with css hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

Please take a look at [this link](http://tural.us/?page=utube). Hover cursor on any movie thumbnail. Have you noticed that, all li elements moving down? How can I fix that problem?

Also, click on any thumbnail, player div will slide down. there is no box shadow under `#player_container` even if I set it in css files

```
#player_container{
    display:none;
    height:510px;    
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/bg/bg_tile.jpg);
    margin-top: -510px;
    padding-top: 20px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

Comment: i don't see no problem in chrome?

Comment: @ptriek there is no box shadow under #player_container even if I set it in css files tried to change z-index, no success

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu ok I'll add to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On video add a transparent border seems to fix it

```
.video {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    width: 228px;
}
```

There is a couple off different way to fix the next part off your question. One quick way is too add another container like

```
<div style="display: block;" class="gradient sh" id="player_container">

    <div class="jquery-youtube-tubeplayer" id="player">

    <div id="tubeplayer-player-container1324082555277"><iframe width="853" height="480" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LxBGDijiii0?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;controls=1&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;start=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;color=red&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http://tural.us" title="YouTube video player" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div></div>.
    <div class="bottomSpan"></div>    
</div>
```

and put your box shadow on this

```
.bottomSpan {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 5px #888888;
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: fixed, 1 of porblems, please take a look at second probem. Updated question

Comment: this is happening because your container videowall is overlapping it, the shaddow is there

Comment: modified my response with a quick solution to your second part

Answer (score 1):

That is because on hover you are adding a border which makes the container 2px bigger

the solution to give the initial class a border

```
.video {
    border: 1px solid #fff
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    width: 228px;
}
```

**Second Problem:**

To make z-index work you need to give it a `position:relative` property

```
#player_container {
   display: none;
   height: 510px;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: url(images/bg/bg_tile.jpg);
   padding-top: 20px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888;
   box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888;
   z-index: 2;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: there is no box shadow under #player_container even if I set it in css files tried to change z-index, no success

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu See my solution to the second problem

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a border when the mouse hovers but not reducing the size of the element. The "height" and "width" of an element, in the W3C box model, describe the size of the *contents* of a block element.  The padding and the border are *added* to that.

Some browsers allow you to switch back to the "border-box" box sizing model:

```
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

However Internet Explorer wont, I don't think, understand that.  Maybe IE9 or 10 would understand:

```
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
```

(You'd put that on the ".video" style.)

*edit* — as to the problem with the shadow on the player: there's no shadow because there's no *room* for a shadow.  If you make the player box "position: absolute", and correspondingly adjust the content somehow (maybe give the "wrapper" div a big top padding the same as the player size) then you'll see a shadow.

You really should be using something like Firebug to play with the CSS interactively.

Comment: IE8 and greater support plain `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: there is no box shadow under #player_container even if I set it in css files tried to change z-index, no success

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu uhh ... this doesn't have anything to do with the box shadow.

Comment: Where did I say that? I fixed 1 of problems, read second issue. Question is updated

Comment: Oh sorry ... well you're probably better off asking a second question, as that issue is completely unrelated to the layout/hover issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me changing the margin on the corresponding < li > would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your mixing things up a bit:

- Your background-image is set on `#player-container` - if you want `#player-container` to have a shadow, you'll need an extra containing div for this background. Right now `#player-container`does have shadow, but since it's 100% wide, and fills the vertical space, the shadow doesn't show.
- Your player is exactly 853px x 480px, so you'll have to set `#player-container` to exactly these dimensions (no padding, no margin, they will be added to the width/height)
- Add padding to the extra containing div, which also holds the background.
- also (but not so important): `#player-container` has `width:100%` - that makes no sense - default is `width:auto`, so `#player-container` will automatically take 100% width

Comment: "Your player is exactly 853px x 480px, so you'll have to set #player-container to exactly these dimensions (no padding, no margin, they will be added to the width/height)" I want it to fit horizontally 100%, there is another div for player inside container